# Android Firebase: How to indicate message failure in chat app

Tags: android, chat, firebase, messaging

So I'm building an app with chat and we're utilizing Firebase to store our conversations. Everything works fine as long as the device is connected to the network. If the device isn't connected to the network, however, Firebase doesn't seem to differentiate between messages that are actually on its servers and messages that aren't.

Is there any way to configure the Android Firebase SDK to let us know when messages weren't delivered to its servers or do we have handle this on our own.

Fyi, the behavior that we're going for is that if a message fails to send, then we should indicate so in the UI and let the user manually try to send it again. We don't want Firebase to automatically send messages for us when the network connection is restored.

The only solution I can think with the Firebase SDK in its current state is to NOT push the message to Firebase if the device isn't connected to the network. This means I'd have to store these message somewhere else, however, and would lead to complicated logic to merge the list of failed messages in with the list of Firebase messages.

Thoughts?

Comment: Many Firebase methods have a completion handler, which triggers after the write operation finishes: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-update It is normal that Firebase continues to write when you're not connected, due to https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-writes-offline . If that works correctly, it already does what you (second to last) paragraph describes.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Unfortunately the completion handler (onComplete()) is fired regardless of whether data is written to the server or not (such as the case where the user doesn't have a network connection). In our case, we actually want to know whether or not data is written to the server.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that: the second link I provided seems to indicate that writes succeed even when the user is offline *because Firebase will apply the writes when the user comes back online*. The only way I can think of in that case it to use a transaction with fireLocalEvents set to false: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#runTransaction(com.firebase.client.Transaction.Handler,%20boolean)

Comment: Thanks Frank, any idea how to do that with a push()?

Comment: Calling `push` without arguments is a pure client-side operation that just generates a new key for you, so by splitting *generate a key* from *set the data* we can solve that. Instead of `push({ newKey: newValue })`, you can also do `push().set({ newKey: newValue })` or `push().transaction(...` (all in JavaScript SDK syntax, but should work similar in Java/on Android).

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't simply monitor `.info/connected`? It stands to reason that if you are not connected, then it wasn't written to the server (yet).